# Install node uglifyjs on Windows from local folder

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, uglifyjs

I'm trying to install uglifyjs on my computer from local folders.

I downloaded all dependencies of uglifyjs, including dependencies of dependencies, and they are all available in my folder `C:\npm\node_modules`

I'm working on Windows XP, and when I'm trying to install uglify-js from `\node_modules\uglify-js` using the command `npm install -g node_modules\uglify-js` (global because I'm on a Windows machine, to be able then to execute uglifyjs using the command: `uglifyjs -o output.js input.js`) it's trying to download dependencies from Internet (I can't because I'm under a security proxy, that's why I downloaded all dependencies manually)

[image]

I tried to install all dependencies manually, it seems to work fine though

`npm list`:

[image]

This is all folders on my node_modules folder

[image]

I installed uglify-js without global command `-g`, it worked fine

[image]

But when I execute the uglifyjs command `node C:\npm\node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs output.js input.js`, I have this error:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to install node modules globally on a Windows machine. Are you using uglify from the command-line or something? If so, you may just need to add something to your environment PATH.

Comment: I tried to install it without-g . The installation worked fine. Though, when I execute the command: C:\npm\node_modules\.bin\uglifyjs -o output.js input.js, I got this error: basedir='dirname "$0$' SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Have you tried just doing `npm install` from the local directory? Are you using a package.json file? If so, you should be able to specify the repo where it lives.

Comment: That's what I did yes. I just edited the post with more information

Comment: Are those backticks? ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are backticks wrapping your dirname, try changing them to single quotation marks:

```
basedir='dirname "$0"'
```

instead of

```
basdir=`dirname "$0"`
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it was backticks, I think there is a bug from the library!

Comment: My pleasure. Let the original dev know if it's a library bug. :)